# Macbook randomly shutdown 4k external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I have a Macbook 16inch connecting to Dell 24inch 4k P2415Q with **Moshi USB-C to Mini DisplayPort**, bought from Apple.
After 1-2 hours the monitor just shut down like there's no signal, macbook still running. I have to turn off and turn on the monitor to reconnect but it keeps happening all day.
I've done these things so far:

- Open / Close lid while connecting to the monitor.
- Switch between ports.
- Reset NVRAM, PRAM, SMC.
- Tested with Macbook 13 (2016), same problem
- Tested with my gaming desktop, same monitor same cable, working well, no issue.

Has anyone experienced same issue before ?

Comment: If you tested with two *different* MacBook computers as you say,  the problem is likely the monitor itself. You need to contact Dell support.  When it “shuts down” are you in the middle of something or did the computer go to sleep?  What USB-C cable are you using?

Comment: @Allan It shut down when i'm working, Im using j5create cable and it ran well for 2 years, the issue started 2 weeks ago.

Comment: The only thing i found on their website is an adapter, not a cable.   Are you using that cable with your gaming rig?

Comment: @Allan yes im using the same cable with my gaming desktop. I alr ordered a usb-c -> miniDP on apple website, will test this one to see how it's going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out the problem is the the monitor. I've bought a new one and it's ok now.
Still don't know why it only happened to Macbooks not windows